# Creating a nested join using SQLAlchemy in a database with 3 tables

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to join three tables together in order to find a value of the third table's id. The SQL statement works correctly, and looks like this:

```
SELECT table_three.id from table three
   JOIN (table_one JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.table_one_id)
   ON table_three.table_two_id = table_two.id
   WHERE table_one.id = x AND table_two.external_id = y AND table three.external_id = z
```

What would the SQL Alchemy code look like for something like this? I have looked at [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/join_conditions/threeway.html), but their query is different than mine, and I can't make sense of the example well enough to apply it to my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that chaining join statements does exactly what we needed all along.

```
result = connection.execute(
   select(Table_three.id)
   .join(Table_two, Table_three.Table_two_id == Table_two.id)
   .join(Table_one, Table_two.Table_one_id == Table_one.id)
   .where(
      and_(
          Table_three.external_id == z,
          Table_two.external_id == y,
          Table_on.id = x
      )
   )
).one_or_none()
```